# How to check if the block is present in a sparse file (for simple copy-on-write)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sparse-matrix, copy-on-write

How to get sparse block size and check if data is present at the given offset in sparse file in reiserfs/ext3 in Linux?

<s>I want to use it to implement simple copy-on-write block device using FUSE.</s>

Or I should better keep a bitmap in a separate file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt)

> The fiemap ioctl is an efficient method for userspace to get file
>   extent mappings. Instead of block-by-block mapping (such as bmap), fiemap
>   returns a list of extents.

There's a quick example of usage in [git://kernel.ubuntu.com/cking/debug-code/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=cking/debug-code/.git;a=tree;f=fiemap;hb=HEAD)fiemap/.  A sparse file will lack extents for the "missing" portions.

Answer (score 3):

Since Linux 3.1, [`lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) provides flags `SEEK_HOLE` and `SEEK_DATA` to navigate to the beginning or end of a hole, so this might be an alternative to the `ioctl` based [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564060/1468366). Haven't tried either in practice, so I don't have any real experience to compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

Well, http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/arch/um/drivers/cow_user.c indicates that User Mode Linux uses an explicit bitmap for this, FWIW.

Comment: Looks like there are already COW devices in Linux (somewhere in UML or in Device Mapper). FUSE thing is probably just not needed...