# Copy sparse files

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I'm trying to understand Linux (UNIX) low-level interfaces and as an exercise want to write a code which will copy a file with holes into a new file (again with holes).

So my question is, how to read from the first file not till the first hole, but till the very end of the file? 
If I'm not mistaken, `read()` returns 0 when reaches the first hole(EOF).

I was thinking about seeking right byte by byte and trying to read this byte, but then I have to know the number of holes in advance.

Comment: What are *files with ***holes****? Never heard of any.

Comment: In sparse files the empty parts are not EOF but NUL (`\0`). So you will never reach EOF until you reached the actual end-of-file. To copy them consider having a look at what `cp` does.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: do you happen to know what `cp` does, to save those of us who are curious from trawling through the source? Presumably there's either a Posix or a Linux API to tell you whether and where a file has sparseness. That's the "low-level interface" the questioner mentions.

Comment: `if (x->sparse_mode == SPARSE_AUTO && S_ISREG(src_open_sb.st_mode) && ST_NBLOCKS (src_open_sb) < src_open_sb.st_size / ST_NBLOCKSIZE) make_holes = true;` - here's the full code; taken from coreutils-8.5: https://gist.github.com/3655373

Comment: Looks like `cp` simply detects zero blocks and turns them into holes. So the result might have more holes than the original input had.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by *holes* you mean sparse files, then you have to [find the holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563305/how-to-check-if-the-block-is-present-in-a-sparse-file-for-simple-copy-on-write) in the input file and recreate them using [lseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) when writing the output file. Since Linux 3.1, you can even use `lseek` to jump to the beginning or end of a hole, as described in great detail in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html).

As ThiefMaster [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299010/copy-sparse-files#comment16500354_12299010), normal file operations will treat holes simply as sequences of zero bytes, so you won't see the EOF you mention.

Comment: Thank you MvG. One more question. In Ubuntu 11.04 (2.6-38) I was able to create a sparse file just by seeking beyond the EOF and writing. When I try it on Ubuntu 12.04 (3.2), ls shows the same number of allocated blocks as if the "hole" is filled with some data. The same happens if I use dd with seeking. Is there anything specific in 3.2 kernel or should sparse files be somehow enabled?

Comment: Don't know. Probably better to ask such stuff about the internal workings of various linux kernel and filesystem implementations at the [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). I repeatedly read that the FS implementation has quite a lot of freedom in implementing sparsity, so perhaps your hole is simply smaller than some threshold. I'm also not sure whether blocks is the right concept for an extent-based ext4, so there might be some incorrect reporting coming from that. Just guessing, though.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I was having this persons exact problem lately- to use the SEEK_HOLE and SEEK_DATA macros you need to have `#define _GNU_SOURCE 1` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

For copies of sparse files, from the `cp` manual;

By default, sparse SOURCE files are detected by a crude heuristic and the  corresponding DEST file is made sparse as well. That is the behavior selected by `--sparse=auto`. Specify `--sparse=always` to create a sparse DEST file whenever the SOURCE file contains a long enough sequence of zero bytes. Use `--sparse=never` to inhibit creation of sparse files.

Thus, try `--sparse=always` if you need to copy a sparse file 'as-is' (still seems affected by an algo)

Answer (score 1):

A file is not presented as if it has any gaps. If your intention is to say that the file has sections on one area of the disk, then more on another, etc., you are not going to be able to see this through a call to `open()` on that file and a series of `read()` calls. You would instead need to `open()` and `read()` the raw disk instead, seeking to sectors on your own.

If your meaning of "holes" in a file is as @ThiefMaster says, just areas of 0 bytes -- these are only "holes" according to your application use of the data; to the file system they're just bytes in a file, no different than any other. In this case, you can copy it through a simple read of the data source and write to the data target, and you will get a full copy (along with what you're calling holes).

Comment: A simple read & write won't recreate the holes, i.e. will turn a sparse file into a dense one, possibly at excessive costs in terms of disk space.